# CGImageRef not being released under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-image

I know this question has been asked before but nothing seems to work.

I have a static method that returns a filtered image using `CIImage` and `CGIImage`, I used the example on [RayWenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22167/beginning-core-image-in-ios-6) and changed it to return an UIImage instead of setting it directly to an UIImageView.

My problem is that the `CGImageRef cgimg` is never being released. Which results in a rather fast memory leak. What am I doing wrong?

```
+ (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)image withFilterName:(NSString *)filterName
{
    if (!image)
        return nil;


    @autoreleasepool {
        CIImage *beginImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectProcess"]
        [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

        CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

        CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

        CGImageRelease(cgimg);

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but because CGImageRef isn't a subclass of NSObject (and hence doesn't have `retain` and `release` selectors), I'm pretty sure ARC doesn't count it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.  What do you do with `newImage`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `cgimg` is being released. I assume you mean that the `CGImage` is not deallocated. You wouldn't expect it to be, since you pass it to `UIImage`, which likely retains it.

Most likely you then later leak the `UIImage` (or keep it around when you didn't mean to, which is similar to a leak). I would audit the code around where you use and release the `UIImage`, and the `CGImageRef` will likely take care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ....

```
+ (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)image withFilterName:(NSString *)filterName
    {
        if (!image)
            return nil;

        CIImage *beginImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectProcess"];
        [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
        CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

        beginImage = nil;
        context = nil;
        filter = nil;
        outputImage = nil;
        CGImageRelease(cgimg);

        return newImage;
    }
```